# Gradle Groovy compilation cannot find javafx classes in tests

Tags: groovy, gradle, javafx

I have the following Groovy test (not the real one, mind you) in a Gradle project (under `src/test/groovy`):

```
import javafx.scene.paint.Color
import org.junit.Test

class MyTest {
    @Test
    void test1() {
        assert Color.AQUAMARINE != Color.BLUE
    }
}
```

The build file is as simple as it gets and declares that I use Java 8 (so JavaFX is in the classpath, always):

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'

compileJava {
    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8
}
...
```

It also has a test dependency on Groovy:

```
    testCompile group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', name: 'groovy-all', version: '2.4.4'
```

Everything works fine, except when I refer to some JavaFX class in the Groovy test.

It fails with this error:

```
MyTest.groovy: 3: unable to resolve class javafx.scene.paint.Color
 @ line 3, column 1.
   import javafx.scene.paint.Color
   ^
```

The Java code compiles fine and I can run my JavaFX application. Only the Groovy tests seem to not be able to see JavaFX.

I've already tried changing the `compileJava` block to `compileGroovy`, `compileTestGroovy`, also together with the `compileJava` block, so that the Groovy compiler sees JavaFX 8, but nothing helped.

How can I fix this?

Gradle version:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 2.2
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2014-11-10 13:31:44 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     aab8521f1fd9a3484cac18123a72bcfdeb7006ec

Groovy:       2.3.6
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013
JVM:          1.8.0_60 (Oracle Corporation 25.60-b23)
OS:           Linux 3.16.0-38-generic amd64
```

Comment: One more thing: JAVA_HOME is set to the Java 8 JDK location...

Answer (score 0):

Changed the Gradle version to 2.7 (latest as of today) and it all works.

If you have the same problem, just use [Gradle's wrapper](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html) and set the Gradle version to the latest version (they move fast, so bugs will exist, but also get fixed quickly).

```
gradle wrapper --gradle-version 2.7
```